# Find all children work items of another work item - RTC

Tags: rtc, java, ibm-jazz

I try to find out how to see if there are children work items to a given one with the JAVA API.
For example, I look up work item XY, then I want to see the ID of all the sub work items related to it, or to get null, if there is none. Has someone done that and can help me out?

Thanks!